# MacOS QT5 / QT6 both installed build issues

Tags: macos, qt, build

I am trying to build a project that depends on QT5 (specifically PX4 SITL using Gazebo simulator).  I have both QT5 and QT6 installed on my machine.  The build is failing because it is picking up QT header files in /usr/local/include.  Those header files are QT6 header files.  My question is why would it do this?
The compiler command doesn't have an include path to /usr/local/include/<QT...>, and I don't have any environment variables that do.  I believe I can uninstall or unlink QT6 to fix this, and I think I am going to do that, but I'd love to know why it doesn't work.

Here is the output from the build (I've added arg! to qstyleoption.h in /usr/local/include/QtWidgets)

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.dir/src/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.cpp.o 
/usr/local/bin/ccache /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_REGEX_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK -DLIBBULLET_VERSION=3.17 -DLIBBULLET_VERSION_GT_282 -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -Dgazebo_user_camera_plugin_EXPORTS -I/Users/jerrymailloux/dev/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/sitl_gazebo/include -I/Users/jerrymailloux/dev/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/build_gazebo -I/usr/local/include/eigen3/eigen3 -I/usr/local/include/gazebo-11/gazebo/msgs -I/Users/jerrymailloux/dev/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/mavlink/include -I/Users/jerrymailloux/dev/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/sitl_gazebo/external/OpticalFlow/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.18.4/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.70.0_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.70.0_1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.70.0_1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-base/1.18.4/include/gstreamer-1.0 -isystem /usr/local/include -isystem /usr/local/include/gazebo-11 -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/bullet/3.17/include/bullet -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/bullet/3.17/include -isystem /usr/local/include/simbody -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/sdformat9/9.6.1_1/include/sdformat-9.6 -isystem /usr/local/include/ignition/math6 -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/ogre1.9/1.9-20160714-108ab0bcc69603dba32c0ffd4bbbc39051f421c9_10/include/OGRE -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/ogre1.9/1.9-20160714-108ab0bcc69603dba32c0ffd4bbbc39051f421c9_10/include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/ogre1.9/1.9-20160714-108ab0bcc69603dba32c0ffd4bbbc39051f421c9_10/include/OGRE/Terrain -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/ogre1.9/1.9-20160714-108ab0bcc69603dba32c0ffd4bbbc39051f421c9_10/include/OGRE/Paging -isystem /usr/local/include/ignition/transport8 -isystem /usr/local/include/ignition/msgs5 -isystem /usr/local/include/ignition/common3 -isystem /usr/local/include/ignition/fuel_tools4 -iframework /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt@5/./mkspecs/macx-clang -isystem /usr/local/include/eigen3 -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.3_2/include/opencv4 -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/fcl/0.7.0/include -isystem /usr/local/include/sdformat-9.6/sdf/.. -isystem /usr/local/include/ignition/cmake2 -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -isystem /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -fPIC -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-address-of-packed-member -fPIC -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.dir/src/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.dir/src/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.dir/src/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.cpp.o -c /Users/jerrymailloux/dev/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/sitl_gazebo/src/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.cpp
In file included from /Users/jerrymailloux/dev/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/sitl_gazebo/src/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.cpp:46:
In file included from /Users/jerrymailloux/dev/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/sitl_gazebo/include/gazebo_user_camera_plugin.h:46:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gazebo-11/gazebo/gui/GuiPlugin.hh:20:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gazebo-11/gazebo/gui/qt.h:44:
In file included from /usr/local/include/QtWidgets/QComboBox:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/QtWidgets/qcombobox.h:45:
In file included from /usr/local/include/QtWidgets/qabstractitemdelegate.h:45:
/usr/local/include/QtWidgets/qstyleoption.h:71:1: error: unknown type name 'arg'
arg!
```

Comment: Update - unlinking qt did fix this. (brew unlink qt).  So somehow /usr/local/include/QT... is being searched before the QT5 folders.

Comment: ^5 I've encountered the exact same issue! I was about to ask a question, when I found yours here … yeah, I could only perform the same workaround as you - no idea why this is happening for me on macOS Monterey 12.5.1, I double-checked that my Kit settings and environment variables e.g. `PATH` were absolutely correct, but they don't seem to be picked up, running CMake directly on the commandline worked for me, just not from inside Qt Creator 8.0.1 … thankfully, I don't need Qt5 and Qt6 side-by-side simultaneously for now, else there would be an issue with this